# How to get Python to gracefully format None and non-existing fields

Tags: python, string-formatting, missing-data

If I write in Python:

```
data = {'n': 3, 'k': 3.141594, 'p': {'a': 7, 'b': 8}}
print('{n}, {k:.2f}, {p[a]}, {p[b]}'.format(**data))
del data['k']
data['p']['b'] = None
print('{n}, {k:.2f}, {p[a]}, {p[b]}'.format(**data))
```

I get:

```
3, 3.14, 7, 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./funky.py", line 186, in <module>
    print('{n}, {k:.2f}, {p[a]}, {p[b]}'.format(**data))
KeyError: 'k'
```

Instead of an error message, **how can I get Python to more gracefully format the None's and non existent fields?**

To give an example, I would like to see in the output something more like:

```
3, 3.14, 7, 8
3, ~, 7, ~
```

Ideally, of course, I would like to be able to specify the string used instead of those missing values.

Comment: **See also:** [python str.format blank values](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+python+str.format+blank+value&ia=web)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The recommendation in [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) is to subclass [Formatter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter):

```
import string
class PartialFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, missing='~~', bad_fmt='!!'):
        self.missing, self.bad_fmt=missing, bad_fmt

    def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
        # Handle a key not found
        try:
            val=super(PartialFormatter, self).get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
            # Python 3, 'super().get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)' works
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            val=None,field_name 
        return val 

    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        # handle an invalid format
        if value==None: return self.missing
        try:
            return super(PartialFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec)
        except ValueError:
            if self.bad_fmt is not None: return self.bad_fmt   
            else: raise

fmt=PartialFormatter()
data = {'n': 3, 'k': 3.141594, 'p': {'a': '7', 'b': 8}}
print(fmt.format('{n}, {k:.2f}, {p[a]}, {p[b]}', **data))
# 3, 3.14, 7, 8
del data['k']
data['p']['b'] = None
print(fmt.format('{n}, {k:.2f}, {p[a]:.2f}, {p[b]}', **data))
# 3, ~~, !!, ~~
```

As set up, it will print `~~` if a field or attribute is not found and `!!` if an invalid format is used given the field value. (Just use `None` for the keyword argument `bad_fmt` if you want the default of a value error raised.)

To handle missing keys, you need to subclass both `get_field` to catch the `KeyError` or `AttributeError` and `format_field` to return a default value for the missing key.

Since you are catching `format_field` errors, you can catch a bad format field as well by catching the `ValueError` from the superclass.

Comment: Thanks, I think this version is more robust. I've tweaked it a bit, so that format errors still throw up exceptions, my version is here: https://gist.github.com/navarroj/7689682

Comment: Bug here I think in that the formatters isn't using it's own `self.missing`: `val=None,field_name` vs `val=self.missing,field_name`

Comment: If you look below under `format_field` you see where `None` is handled with `if value==None: return self.missing`

Answer (score 10):

If you're able to do the formatting separately you could use `Template.safe_substitute` which gracefully handles missing values:

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> t = Template("$a $b $c")
>>> t.safe_substitute(a=3)
'3 $b $c'
```

Comment: I also thought about that. But then how do I replace the non-substituted fields with `~` or some other string? Also, of course, I do want to format floats, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The `str.format()` method doesn't give you a direct method to handle missing keys or replace values.

You *can* add a layer of indirection; pass in a mapping that handles missing and `None` values, and alter the format to use just that argument:

```
class PlaceholderFormatValue():
    def __format__(self, spec):
        return '~'
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        # handle further nested item access
        return self

class formatting_dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        value = self.get(name)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # rewrap nested dictionaries to handle missing nested keys
            value = type(self)(value)
        return value if value is not None else PlaceholderFormatValue()

print('{0[n]}, {0[k]:.2f}, {0[p][a]}, {0[p][b]}'.format(formatting_dict(data)))
```

Now all slots refer to positional argument `0`, which is treated like a dictionary, but key lookups always succeed and both missing values and `None` are replaced by a placeholder value.

Here the `PlaceholderFormatValue()` ensures that regardless of what the format spec gives, the value can be interpolated into the format. This makes `{0[k]:.2f}` work, for example.

By wrapping any `dict` values and having `PlaceholderFormatValue` handle item access, the above can also handle failure to provide nested keys or whole dictionaries:

```
>>> data = {'n': 3, 'k': 3.141594, 'p': {'a': 7, 'b': 8}}
>>> del data['k']
>>> data['p']['b'] = None
>>> print('{0[n]}, {0[k]:.2f}, {0[p][a]}, {0[p][b]}'.format(formatting_dict(data)))
3, ~, 7, ~
>>> del data['p']['a']
>>> print('{0[n]}, {0[k]:.2f}, {0[p][a]}, {0[p][b]}'.format(formatting_dict(data)))
3, ~, ~, ~
>>> del data['p']
>>> print('{0[n]}, {0[k]:.2f}, {0[p][a]}, {0[p][b]}'.format(formatting_dict(data)))
3, ~, ~, ~
```

Comment: This is nice, but still doesn't quite work. If I remove the `b` key inside of `data['p']` I still get an error (I guess because formatting `0[p]` returned a regular `dict` and not a `formatting_dict`), also if I remove the whole `p` in `data` then it breaks as it's trying to script the non-scriptable `PlaceholderFormatValue`.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro: Right, adjusted for those two cases.

Comment: `The str.format() method doesn't give you a direct method to handle missing keys or replace values.` -- Sure it does. Just [subclass Formatter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter).

Comment: @dawg: That is *not* the `str.format()` method, however. That is the `Formatter` class.

Comment: Quoting the docs: 'The Formatter class in the string module allows you to create and customize your own string formatting behaviors **using the same implementation as the built-in format() method.**' Why do you say it is not the same?

Comment: @dawg: Because you are not calling `str.format()`; you are using a separate class. :-) Which I admit I should have looked at, but it is *not* exactly the same thing. :-)

Comment: @dawg `Formatter` is _Deprecated since version 3.4: Due to lack of usage, the formatter module has been deprecated_. Cited from [Python official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/formatter.html)