# String format with optional dict key-value

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting, missing-data

Is there any way to format string with dict but optionally without key errors?

This works fine:

```
opening_line = '%(greetings)s  %(name)s !!!'
opening_line % {'greetings': 'hello', 'name': 'john'}
```

But let's say I don't know the name, and I would like to format above line 
only for `'greetings'`. Something like,

```
 opening_line % {'greetings': 'hello'}
```

Output would be fine even if:

```
'hii %(name)s !!!'  # keeping name un-formatted
```

But this gives `KeyError` while unpacking

Is there any way?

Comment: **See also:** [py str.format missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248355/how-to-get-python-to-gracefully-format-none-and-non-existing-fields)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), this will allow you to specify a default value for keys which don't exist in the dictionary. For example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: 'UNKNOWN')
>>> d.update({'greetings': 'hello'})
>>> '%(greetings)s  %(name)s !!!' % d
'hello  UNKNOWN !!!'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some alternates to defaultDict,

```
greeting_dict = {'greetings': 'hello'}

if 'name' in greeting_dict :
    opening_line = '{greetings} {name}'.format(**greeting_dict)
else:
    opening_line = '{greetings}'.format(**greeting_dict)

print opening_line
```

Maybe even more succinctly, use dictionary get to set per parameter defaults,

```
'{greetings} {name}'.format(greetings=greeting_dict.get('greetings','hi'),
                            name=greeting_dict.get('name',''))
```

Comment: I'd extract commonality in `if/else` and instead, `fmt = '{greetings} {name}' if 'name' in greeting_dict else '{greetings}'; print(fmt.format(**greeting_dict))`.

Answer (score 2):

For the record:

```py
info = {
    'greetings':'DEFAULT',
    'name':'DEFAULT',
    }
opening_line = '{greetings} {name} !!!'

info['greetings'] = 'Hii'
print opening_line.format(**info)
# Hii DEFAULT !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as yours and decided to create a library to solve this problem: [pyformatting](https://pypi.org/project/pyformatting/).
Here is the solution to your problem with pyformatting:

```py
>>> from pyformatting import optional_format
>>> opening_line = '{greetings}  {name} !!!'
>>> optional_format(opening_line, greetings='hii')
'hii  {name} !!!'
```

The only problem is pyformatting doesn't support python 2. pyformatting supports python 3.1+
If i see any feedback on the need for 2.7 support i think i will add that support.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `UserDict` and customize `__missing__` to your liking with `.format_map()`:

```
from collections import UserDict


class FormatMapper(UserDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return f'{key=} is MISSING'


info = FormatMapper({'greetings': 'hello', 'not_name': 'john'})
opening_line = '{greetings}  {name} !!!'

print(opening_line.format_map(info))
```

Output:

```
hello  key='name' is MISSING !!!
```