# Ignore str.format(**foo) if key doesn't exist in foo

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, escaping, string-interpolation

I am trying to get an email template together. The message content will be dependent on values within a dictionary. However, the dictionary might not contain all the keys each time.

This currently is fine as all values are in the dictionary (`'Title'`, `'Surname'`, `'Additional Details'`):

```
practise_dict = {"Additional Details":"blah blah blah blah", "Title": "Mr", "Surname": "Smith", "URL": "/test/tester"}

msg = """From: John Smith <no-reply@somethingsomething.co.uk>
To: {Title} {Surname} <blah@blahblah.co.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: New Website Enquiry
This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format
{Additional Details}
<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
`""".format(**practise_dict)

print(msg)
```

In the `msg` variable I am trying to create my 'template'. This means that I need to have all possible items that could be in the dictionary.

For example the next piece would fail as it is looking for `'Date'` that doesn't exist in this dictionary:

```
practise_dict = {"Additional Details":"blah blah blah blah", "Title": "Mr", "Surname": "Smith", "URL": "/test/tester"}

msg = """From: John Smith <no-reply@somethingsomething.co.uk>
To: {Title} {Surname} <blah@blahblah.co.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: New Website Enquiry
This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format
{Additional Details}
{Date}
<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
`""".format(**practise_dict)

print(msg)
```

Is there a way to ask it to ignore a string substitution if it doesn't exist as a key in the look-up dictionary?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20608470/3001761

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Template` and `safe_substitute` for that:

```
from string import Template

practise_dict = {"Additional_Details":"blah blah blah blah", "Title": "Mr", "Surname": "Smith", "URL": "/test/tester"}

msg = """From: John Smith <no-reply@somethingsomething.co.uk>
To: $Title $Surname <blah@blahblah.co.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: New Website Enquiry
This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format
$Additional_Details
$Date
<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
`"""

s = Template(msg).safe_substitute(**practise_dict)
print(s)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
From: John Smith <no-reply@somethingsomething.co.uk>
To: Mr Smith <blah@blahblah.co.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: New Website Enquiry
This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format
blah blah blah blah
$Date
<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I've actually used a combination of the solutions. I'm using this idea of the defaults dictionary and safe_substitute. Thank you both.

Comment: An excellent replacement for `envsubst(1)`. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to tell `format` that some substitutions are optional. However, here are two workarounds.

If there's only one missing field, try something like:

```
msg = """...""".format(Date=practise_dict.pop("Date", ""), # handle optional field
                       **practise_dict) # pass the rest as before
```

However, note that this modifies `practise_dict`, and will be awkward if there are several values to deal with.

If there may be multiple fields missing, or you don't want to modify the dictionary, the following would probably be preferable:

```
defaults = {"Date": "", "Additional Details": ""} # define optional fields
defaults.update(practise_dict) # override user data where available
msg = """...""".format(**defaults)
```

Both approaches will still fail for keys you haven't explicitly provided an alternative for, which allows you to make some fields mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

#### In case you don't know the keys yet:

You can just write a dict subclass, which will return the key if it was not found in the dictionary:

```
class FailsafeDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            return "{" + str(item) + "}"
        # end try
    # end def
# end class
```

This works by overriding the `__getitem__(item)` function, which handles the `dict[item]` call.

You can than use it like this:

```
f = FailsafeDict({"yo": "lo", "foo": "bar"})
text = "{yo}! {lol}! {foo}!".format(**f)
print(text)
```

Which prints `lo! {lol}! bar!`.

In your case that would be

```
msg = """...""".format(**FailsafeDict(practise_dict))
```

Comment: `text = "{yo}! {lol}! {foo}!".format(**f)` still gives me KeyError. I am on Python 3.10.9.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment in @luckydonald answer so I will add it here my comment. `format_map()` should be used instead of classic `format()`.

```
class FailsafeDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            return "{" + str(item) + "}"

f = FailsafeDict({"yo": "lo", "foo": "bar"})
text = "{yo}! {lol}! {foo}!".format_map(f)
print(text) 

> "lo! {lol}! bar!"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).