# Modify str.format function in python

Tags: python, regex, string, format

What *str.format* does almost exactly I'm looking for. 
A functionality I would like to add to format() is to use optional keywords and for that I have to use another special character (I guess).

So str.format can do that:

```
f = "{ID1}_{ID_optional}_{ID2}"
f.format(**{"ID1" : " ojj", "ID2" : "makimaki", "ID_optional" : ""})
# Result: ' ojj__makimaki' #
```

I can't really use optional ID's. If the dictionary does not contain "ID_optional" it produces KeyError. I think it should be something like this to mark the optional ID:

```
f = "{ID1}_[IDoptional]_{ID2}"
```

Another thing: I have lot of template strings to process which are use [] rather than {}. So the best way would be to add the special characters as an argument for the format function.

**So the basic question is there a sophisticated way to modify the original function?** Or I should write my own format function based on *str.format* and *regular expressions*?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28094590/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to define your own [Formater](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting). You can inherit the standard one and override get_field to return some reasonable default for your use case. See the link for some more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You if/else and format based on whether the dic has the key or not:

```
f = "{ID1}_{ID_optional}_{ID2}" if "ID_optional" in d else "{ID1}_{ID2}"
```

A dict lookup is `0(1)` so it is cheap just to check