# Default kwarg values for Python's str.format() method

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, default-value

I'm looking to try and keep pluralisation of existing strings as simple as possible, and was wondering if it was possible to get `str.format()` to interpret a default value when looking for kwargs. Here's an example:

```
string = "{number_of_sheep} sheep {has} run away"
dict_compiled_somewhere_else = {'number_of_sheep' : 4, 'has' : 'have'}

string.format(**dict_compiled_somewhere_else)
# gives "4 sheep have run away"

other_dict = {'number_of_sheep' : 1}
string.format(**other_dict)
# gives a key error: u'has'
# What I'd like is for format to somehow default to the key, or perhaps have some way of defining the 'default' value for the 'has' key 
# I'd have liked: "1 sheep has run away"
```

Cheers

Comment: Related: [Plural String Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872366/plural-string-formatting)

Comment: Nice link, I should have seen that first

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248355/how-to-get-python-to-gracefully-format-none-and-non-existing-fields

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), `string.format(**other_dict)` is not available.

> If the index or keyword refers to an item that does not exist, then an
>       IndexError/KeyError should be raised.

A hint for solving the problem is in `Customizing Formatters`, `PEP 3101`. That uses `string.Formatter`.

I improve the example in `PEP 3101`:

```
from string import Formatter

class UnseenFormatter(Formatter):
    def get_value(self, key, args, kwds):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            try:
                return kwds[key]
            except KeyError:
                return key
        else:
            return Formatter.get_value(key, args, kwds)

string = "{number_of_sheep} sheep {has} run away"
other_dict = {'number_of_sheep' : 1}

fmt = UnseenFormatter()
print fmt.format(string, **other_dict)
```

The output is

```
1 sheep has run away
```

Comment: I think this is the clearest method, other than those shown in [yesterday's thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872366/plural-string-formatting). In my comment I made a few alterations to make it a bit more DRY

Comment: PS a link to PEP 3101 would have been nice, and warranted a +1 ;-)

Comment: `return` is missing before `Formatter.get_value(key, args, kwds)`, positional arguments don't work without that. Also, I don't think you need to implement `__init__` at all, since it only calls parent's `__init__`.

Comment: may i suggest checking isinstance(key, basestring) so that this still works if the key is a unicode

Answer (score 2):

Can't see the advantage. You have to check the plurality anyway, cause normally you don't have a fixed number of sheep

```
class PluralVerb(object):
    EXCEPTIONS = {'have': 'has'}
    def __init__(self, plural):
        self.plural = plural

    def __format__(self, verb):
        if self.plural:
            return verb
        if verb in self.EXCEPTIONS:
            return self.EXCEPTIONS[verb]
        return verb+'s'

number_of_sheep = 4
print "{number_of_sheep} sheep {pl:run} away".format(number_of_sheep=number_of_sheep, pl=PluralVerb(number_of_sheep!=1))
print "{number_of_sheep} sheep {pl:have} run away".format(number_of_sheep=number_of_sheep, pl=PluralVerb(number_of_sheep!=1))
```

Comment: This is nice and DRY (singular/plurals are defined beforehand), but personally I'd prefer to define the singular in my format string, and have the plural substituted in if need be. Shows another method to mskimm's

Answer (score 1):

Based on mskimm and Daniel answer, here's a solution that predefines the singular/plural words (whilst correcting a couple of typos in mskimm's).

The only downside is the hard coding of the keyword arg `number` (so I can no longer use `number_of_sheep`)

```
from string import Formatter

class Plural(Formatter):
    PLURALS = {'has' : 'have'}
    def __init__(self):
        super(Plural, self).__init__()

    def get_value(self, key, args, kwds):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            try:
                return kwds[key]
            except KeyError:
                if kwds.get('number', 1) == 1:
                    return key
                return self.PLURALS[key]
        return super(Plural, self).get_value(key, args, kwds)

string = "{number} sheep {has} run away"
fmt = Plural()
print fmt.format(string, **{'number' : 1})
print fmt.format(string, **{'number' : 2})
```

Comment: A nice solution. I thought that the question was about `safe` substitution not `plurals`.

Comment: I guess you're right, I worded it to refer to safe substitution, but my case was for the use of plurals. Still, your answer got the check mark :)