# Python 3.6+ formatting strings from unpacking dictionaries with missing keys

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, string-formatting

In Python3.4 you could do the following thing:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return "{%s}" % key
```

And then something like:

```
d = MyDict()
d['first_name'] = 'Richard'
print('I am {first_name} {last_name}'.format(**d))
```

Printing, as expected:

```
I am Richard {last_name}
```

But this snippet won't work in Python3.6+, returning a `KeyError` while trying to get the `last_name` value from the dictionary, is there any workaround for that string formatting to work in the same way as in Python3.4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) instead of `format`, following my example:

```
print('I am {first_name} {last_name}'.format_map(d))
```

Printed

```
I am Richard {last_name}
```

As expected.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.6+, you can use formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return f'{{{key}}}'

d = MyDict()
d['first_name'] = 'Richard'

print(f"I am {d['first_name']} {d['last_name']}")

# I am Richard {last_name}
```

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this solution, the problem was that I had several strings a couple of hundred lines long, so changing value by values was not an option (highly error prone), thanks for the alternative, though!